# Mysterious Black Markers on Google Maps iOS / Android SDK

Tags: android, ios, sdk, maps, google-maps-markers

We are seeing mysterious black markers added to our map which we did not place.
We have no idea where they come from or how to remove them.
Looking for assistance, thank you. Included is a screenshot of an offending marker.
[image: Black MArker in Middle]